# float to string in C++ using NRF MCU and Zephyr

Tags: c++, string, floating-point, nrf52, nrf52840

I simply want to convert a float to string. Normally this is done using C++ standard library with the command `to_string(float)`. However when I program this on my MCU nrf52840 I got garbage.

This is the code

```
#include <zephyr/kernel.h>
#include <zephyr/logging/log.h>
#include<float.h>
#include<string>


LOG_MODULE_REGISTER(main);
using namespace std;


int main(void){

float myFloat=3.3;

string str;

str=to_string(myFloat);

char buffer[64];
int ret = snprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, "%f", myFloat);

if (ret < 0) {
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
if (ret >= sizeof buffer) {
    // / Result was truncated - resize the buffer and retry.
}

LOG_INF("end");
}
```

The project file has the standard C++ library enabled:

```
CONFIG_LOG=y

CONFIG_STD_CPP20=y
CONFIG_CPP_MAIN=y

CONFIG_CPLUSPLUS=y
CONFIG_LIB_CPLUSPLUS=y
```

During debugger I got following garbage:

[image]

The length is completely wrong and also the value.
Trying to do the same task and convert to chars also fails.

Converting integers with `to_string` works.
And logging floats using `printk` and `LOG_INF` also works. Therefore, I have to miss something.

Comment: During debugging, what line are you on in the source code when your debugger displayed that state?

Comment: at the the end  put the breakpoint at ´LOG_INF("end");´

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add
`CONFIG_NEWLIB_LIBC=y CONFIG_NEWLIB_LIBC_NANO=n` to the project config file, even if zephyr tells it is obsolete. It fixes the string error and sprintf error.